# python - how do I define xtick frequency in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below are my codes of how am plotting my charts:

```
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    np.cumsum(returns[['low', 'med','high']]).plot(ax=axs[0])
    sig.plot(ax=axs[1])
    plt.show()
```

The output of the 2nd subplot is what I want to change

[image]

I just want 0 and 1 and no values in between.

I tried adding the below after `sig.plot(ax=axs[1])`

```
axs[1].xticks(np.arange(0, 2, 1))
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want Y ticks: `axs[1].set_yticks(np.arange(0, 2, 1))`

Comment: nope that didnt work, got this error -     
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'yticks'

Comment: use set_yticks.